# Locked Windows 8 For POS

Tags: windows-8, point-of-sale, windows-rt

I've developed a Windows 7 app using the Surface SDK for a POS application (ordering drink/food from your table using tactile screen).

I'd like to start migrating to using a Metro App, as I fear the Surface SDK will die soon (and I'd like the app to evolve).

My biggest issue, concerns Windows 8 and how to "lock" it for public usage.

Basically I'd like the machine to boot and run my metro app, and of course prevent the user from accessing the OS using charms or other gestures.

I know how to secure a Windows 7 and older, but somehow the new metro system feels like it's going to be harder to do such a simple task.

Answer (score 0):

I do believe the same GPO on Windows 7 is applicable to Windows 8 as well, with a few exceptions. There are some discussions on the net which I found useful (I needed to lock down a few Windows 8 tablets and these got me going). The only problem is that I haven't figure out how to lock down an RT tablet.

[Windows 8 Tablet Lockdown](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w8itproinstall/thread/2f52d7ef-8597-43c1-9a36-7a69c4966091/)

[Discussion on locking down windows 8 start screen](http://www.eightforums.com/general-support/18239-does-windows-8-support-creating-locked-down-start-screen.html)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to GPO, something else we've done for touch devices(in our case Surface Pro) is build a custom enclosure that overlaps all the screen edges(so you're putting the device in a case but the case covers up a bit of the touchscreen) so users' can't bring up the Charm menu, switch apps or use the "Microsoft" button. You can turn off switching from previous app by swiping from the left in the OS.

It is a bit severe but you are putting it in a public setting so I imagine you were planning to put it in an enclosure anyway.